# Capturing secondary / tertiary stream to terminal / TTY

Tags: node.js, unix, terminal, tty

See picture below. I run a command from the terminal which starts process A, which starts a server (process B), and the server in turn will start workers (processes C). I want to stream the stdout/stderr of the server to some log file, but I want the stdout and stderr of the workers to stream back to the terminal. All processes here are Node.js processes.

No idea how to do this or if it's possible. My only guess as to how it might work is if the terminal session has some sort of handle or id which I can use and tell the worker processes to stream to that handle or id. I don't know enough about *nix to know how this works. Any explanation would help.

Here's a visual:

[image]

Comment: LOL sorry the "visual" was on my kitchen counter for a few days, on the left side of the picture, it says "stream stdout/stderr back to terminal"

Answer (score 4):

Using Node.js (since all the processes from the OP are Node.js processes), here is one solution I have discovered.

> **step 1**,  in process A, get the tty identity of the current
>   terminal/tty

```
const tty = String(cp.execSync('tty', {stdio:['inherit','pipe','pipe']})).trim();
```

> **step 2**, pass the tty value from process A to process B => I pass that
>   dynamic value (a string) to the child process using socket.io (you
>   could also use IPC)

```
this.emit('tty-value', tty);
```

> **step 3** In the child process B, I use `fd = fs.openSync(tty)` to get the
>   right file descriptor.

`const fd = fs.openSync(tty)`

> **step 4** Then I can write to the terminal that I want to write to with the following

```
const strm = fs.createWriteStream(null, {fd: fd});
```

So when process B creates child process C, it can make the calls necessary to pipe the stdout/stderr from process C to the above stream.

...this took me all day to figure out, so leaving this here for anyone to see

Comment: great answer. Had to do `fs.openSync(tty, 'w+')` since the api has changed

Answer (score 0):

Nice job figuring out the tty thing.  Not sure if there is an easier way to do exactly that, but I have a few ideas that involve cheating on your question in a way but are probably better in the long run anyway.

1. Use a logging framework like `winston` or `bunyan`.  Or a structured logging system like `timequerylog`.  The logging frameworks will allow for multiple loggers, one can go to a file and another can go to stdout.
2. Use the Cluster built-in Node module to create workers and have the workers send messages to the master with events/data. The master could then log those stdout.

Comment: Yeah it depends on the use case...my use case is different because I am writing a library and need to give the user of the lib a certain user-friendly experience, I want them to be able to see the stdout from the workers in the same terminal they issue the command, for convenience only

Comment: In other words, I am already sending the stdout from the workers to a separate log file, which the user can tail using tail -F. But on top of that, I also wanted to send the stdout from the workers back to the terminal, that was the challenge.